# Mule - use flow in CXF service

Tags: java, mule, cxf

I'm trying to build a CXF service with a flow connected to it.

So far, my flow has this:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

<flow name="b2bFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/b2b" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service  doc:name="CXF" serviceClass="com.acme.Soap">
        <cxf:jaxb-databinding/>
    </cxf:jaxws-service>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <component class="com.acme.SoapImpl" doc:name="Java"/>
</flow>
```

My problem is that I don't want to write all the logic inside the service implementation.
If I put my logic right after the CXF component, the payload is an `Object[]` and if I put my logic after the call to the service implementation (the Java component), I only have access to the object the service implementation returns.

I tried to call a subflow from the component code or write the arguments in flowVars, but with no success.

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want you implementation in the service class, maybe look at a `cxf:proxy-service` instead of a `cxf:jaxws-service.` This will allow you host and validate against a WSDL and schema but allow you access to the raw payload to handle how you want in Mule configuration.

More info here: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Proxying+Web+Services+with+CXF